# ¿Cómo agregar Google Analytics en mi aplicación Android?

Tags: android, google-play

Quiero utilizar Google Analytics para recopilar más información sobre el uso de mis aplicaciones.

> **¿Cómo puedo agregar Google Analytics en mi aplicación Android?**

Answer (score 6):

Cuando estudié los servicios de Google me pareció interesante el poder controlar que volumen de visitas tiene mi aplicación o cuales son las activities que más interés generan de mi app.

Siguiendo estos pasos podrás realizar lo que preguntas, incluso te dejo al final los enlaces de donde aprendí en su momento:

**1 - Crear una cuenta en Google Analytics**

Lo primero que tienes que hacer y que supongo que ya tendrás, sera crear una cuenta de Google Analytics y crear una nueva propiedad para tu app. Con esto, obtendrás un `ID de segimiento` necesario para poder ver las estadisticas de tu aplicación, ademas de ser recomendable crear un nuevo `ID de seguimiento` independiente del que tengas ya en tu web (en caso de ya tener uno).

Para crear un nuevo procedimiento, solamente tienes que entrar en tu cuenta de Google Analytics e ir a la pestaña `Administrador`. Una vez allí, te dirijes a la columna `Porpiedades` y seleccionas el campo `Crear nueva propiedad`. Justo como esta en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez en la configuración de la nueva propiedad, selecciona la opción `Aplicación para móviles` y rellena todos los campos y cuando haya finalizado, clica sobre `Obtener ID de seguimiento` y finalmente ya tendrás tu ID tipo UA-XXXXXXXX-X para el seguimiento de la app.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**2.- Configurar tu proyecto Android**

Dirigete al archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` de tu proyecto y añade los permisos de acceso al estado de la red y a Internet:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.analytics">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

  <application android:name="AnalyticsApplication">
    ...
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Luego añadimos el complemento de los servicios de Google al Gradle:

`build.gradle (Project: XXXXX)`: es el primer archivo del gradle. La siguient linea la tienes que introducir en el apartado `dependencies{}`:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
```

`build.gradle (Module: app)`: en este archivo tendrás que añadir dentro de `dependencies{}` la primera linea de codigo y la segunda, fuera de las dependencias, de la siguiente forma:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'

    // Linea a añadir
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'
}
// Linea a añadir fuera de depencendies
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**3.- Obtener un archivo de configuración**

Si pinchas en [este enlace](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=analytics&cnturl=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fanalytics%2Fdevguides%2Fcollection%2Fandroid%2Fv4%2Fapp%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20Analytics&hl=es), solo tendras que seguir los pasos para conseguir un archivo de configuración. Estos pasos son faciles, así que no tendrás problema.

**4.- Agregar el archivo de configuración al proyecto**

Una vez tengas ya el archivo de configuración, copialo en la carpeta `app/` de tu aplicación. Puedes acceder a traver de la ruta `C:\Users\(nombre_usuario)\AndroidStudioProjects\(nombre_app)\app`, en caso de Windows.

**5.- Agregar el seguimiento de pantalla**

Ahora tendrás que crear una subclase `Application` y proporcionar un método que devuelva el objeto de seguimiento de tu aplicación como este:

```
import android.app.Application;

import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;

public class AnalyticsApplication extends Application {
  private Tracker mTracker;

  synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker() {
    if (mTracker == null) {
      GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
      mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
    }
    return mTracker;
  }
}
```

Ahora en tu activity o fragment, debes introducir las siguientes lineas para obtener la instancia de `Tracker` en el método 'onCreate()':

```
AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) getApplication();
mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();
```

Cuando quieras registrar un cambio de pantalla, tienes que poner el codigo siguiente en metodos donde no moleste demasiado al la ejecuvion principal, por ejemplo, en el método `onResume()` en caso de ponerlo en una `Activity` o en `onPageSelected` en caso de un `ViewPager`:

```
Log.i(TAG, "Setting screen name: " + name);
mTracker.setScreenName("Image~" + name);
mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
```

Este codigo, se tiene que agregar en todos los activities u objetos que quieras registrar en Analytics.

Con esto ya tienes lo básico para poder empezar a enviar, aunque no esta todo, te he introducido en el Google Analytics. Te recomiendo que te mires estos enlaces de donde saqué la información cuando lo utilicé, me fueron muy útiles y seguro que a ti también.

- [Probar Analytics para Android (ejemplo)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/start?hl=es)
- [Agregar Analytics a aplicaciones para Android](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/?hl=es)
- [Guía de implementación de aplicaciones móviles](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/mobile-implementation-guide?hl=es#intro)
- [Funciones opcionales](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/optional-features?hl=es)
- [Configuración avanzada: SDK de Android (versión 4)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/advanced?hl=es#overview)

Si tienes dudas o algún problema, avísame sin ninguna duda e intentare ayudarte. Siempre viene bien saber las experiencias de los demás.

Mucha suerte!!

Comment: Hola @Vicky. Respecto a esto: *No te explico todo el procedimiento porque entonces este post se haría enorme, pero con los enlaces de arriba tienes más que suficiente* El sitio consiste en eso: **proveer el contenido aquÍ** en lugar de depender de enlaces externos. Por favor brinda el contenido relevante aquí en la respuesta, sino lastimosamente esto no es más que un comentario tan grande que no cabe dentro de los 500 caracteres de comentario. Por favor revisa [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Gracias @LuiggiMendoza , la verdad es que son relativamente nueva en Stackoverflow y no sabia que no se podían simplificar una respuesta poniendo solo los enlaces de donde poder aprender. Lo he modificado, pero aun así, como he dicho, la pregunta sigue siendo demasiado amplia como para explicarlo todo. Tiene el contenido relevante, ahora le toca a el seguir aprendiendo en los enlaces que le proporciono. Gracias por informarme.

Comment: tu aporte es más que excelente. Sí, esta es una pregunta muy amplia y usualmente este tipo de preguntas son cerradas, pero tu respuesta es simplemente brillante. Te agradezco como moderador y como usuario por tu esfuerzo :D espero que continúes participando en el sitio, se necesitan personas como tú.